# NuSMV not getting installed

Tags: installation, nusmv

I am not able to install NuSMV-2.6.0-win64 on windows 10 OS.I have downloaded this successfully,but am not able to install from 'bin'folder,which has been extracted.

Comment: Please provide the error screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run an installer. You can just run the binary executable that is located in the bin folder. If you look in the bin folder there should be a file named `nusmv-xxx-.exe` and that file you can run.

BTW you can also use the NuSeen plugin in eclipse with NuSMV for convenient source formatting and syntax highlighting.

Comment: I tried this,but the response from microsoft is that the file is not compatible for the Os that is Windows 10.What can I do?

Comment: @purnachandra check that you downloaded the right architecture version (32 vs 64 bit). I just downloaded the 64-bit package, uncompressed it with 7-zip and executed NuSMV inside a terminal on Windows 10.

Comment: I downloaded the correct NuSMV-win64 but the fault is persisting,may be a software error in the PC!

Comment: @purnachandra try copy-and-paste `$ENV:PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` in the **power shell**, what does it print?

Answer (score 0):

with the help of a friend I did the following:I downloaded the unzipped (NuSMV-2.6.0-win64)file on the desktop folder(SMV) and pasted the file to be verified to the 'bin' of the NuSMV file.Then,using 'cmd'command,the directory was changed to the required path applying the 'Chdir'command.In my case it is C:\users\dell\desktop\SMV\NuSMV-2.6.0-win64\bin>NuSMV *filename*'ENTER'.With this,the file could be verified in the batch mode and I was successful.